# I am trying to sorting data in django the data is coming from different table in different dropdown but It is giving empty page

Tags: python, django, django-views

**Basically I am making a search engine for car's selling company in this search engine data is coming from different models when I click the search button then blank page will open no data is showing related to dropdown empty page is opening, how can I get the perfect match I need help to solve this problem I will be very thankful to you**

**home.html**

```
<form action="/searchdd" method="GET" id="indexForm" data-cars-url="{% url 'ajax_load_cars' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
     
      <div class=" col-md-3">
        <label for="" class="white">Make</label>
        <select id="companyddl" name="companyname" class="searchengine dp-list">
          <option disabled selected="true" value="">--Select Make--</option>
          {% for company in companies %}
          <option value="{{company.CompanyID}}">{{company.CompanyName}}</option>
          {% endfor %}
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class=" col-md-3">
        <label for="" class="white">Model</label>
        <select id="carddl" name="carname" class="searchengine dp-list">
          <option disabled selected="true" value="">--Select Model--</option>                           
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label for="" class="white">From Year</label>
        <select name="fromdate" id="fromdate" class="dp-list">
          <option disabled selected="true" value="">--select Year--</option>
          {% for manf in manufac %}
          <option value="{{manf.ManufacturingYMID}}">{{manf.ManufacturingDate}}</option>
          {% endfor %}
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label for="" class="white">To Year</label>
        <select name="todate" id="todate" class="dp-list">
          <option disabled selected="true" value="">--select Year--</option>
          {% for manf in manufac %}
          <option value="{{manf.ManufacturingYMID}}">{{manf.ManufacturingDate}}</option>
          {% endfor %}
        </select>
      </div>
     
      
    </div>
    
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="row"> 

      <div class="dropdown my-2 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
        <label for="" class="white">Type </label>
        <select name="typ" id="typ" class="searchengine dp-list" style="padding-right: 7px; margin-left: 3px;">
          <option disabled selected="true" value="">--Select Type--</option>
          {% for ty in type %}
          <option value="{{ty.TypeID}}">{{ty.TypeName}}</option>
          {% endfor %}
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="dropdown my-2 col-md-3 col-sm-12"> 
        <label for="" class="white">Steering </label>          
        <select name="steering" id="steering" class="searchengine dp-list">
          <option value="">--Select Steering--</option>    
          {% for str in steer %}          
          <option value="{{str.SteeringID}}">{{str.SteeringName}}</option>
          {% endfor %}
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3"></div>
      <div class=" col-md-3">
        <label class="white">Search </label>            
        <button class="btn-dark" type="submit" value="search"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Search Here&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>            
      </div>
              
    </div>
  </div>
  
</form>
```

**urls.py**

```
    urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home),
    path('search', views.search, name='search'),    
    path('load-cars', views.load_cars, name='ajax_load_cars'),
    path('searchdd', views.searchdd, name='searchdd'),
    ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**models.py**

```
      class Car(models.Model):
          CarID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
          CarName = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Car Name")
          company = models.ForeignKey(Company, verbose_name="Company Name", 
on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
default="")
          type = models.ForeignKey(CarType, verbose_name="Vehicle Type", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
          CarImage = models.ImageField(upload_to='productimg', verbose_name="Vehicle Image")
          RefNo = models.CharField(max_length=500,verbose_name="Ref No", null=True, blank=True)
          ChassisNo = models.CharField(max_length=500,verbose_name="Chassis No", null=True, 
blank=True)
          ModelCode = models.CharField(max_length=500,verbose_name="Model Code", null=True, 
blank=True)
          EngineSize = models.CharField(max_length=500,verbose_name="Engine Size", null=True, blank=True)
          Location = models.CharField(max_length=500,verbose_name="Location", null=True, blank=True)
          Version = models.CharField(max_length=500,verbose_name="Version/Class", null=True, blank=True)
          Drive = models.CharField(max_length=500,verbose_name="Drive", null=True, blank=True)
          Transmission = models.CharField(max_length=500,verbose_name="Transmission", null=True, blank=True)
          mdate = models.ForeignKey(ManufacturingYM, verbose_name="Manufacturing Year", on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
          Mileage = models.CharField(max_length=500,verbose_name="Mileage", null=True, blank=True)
          EngineCode = models.CharField(max_length=500,verbose_name="Engine Code", null=True, blank=True)
          steering = models.ForeignKey(Steering, verbose_name="Steering", on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")        
          ExtColor = models.CharField(max_length=500,verbose_name="Ext Color", null=True, blank=True)
          Fuel = models.CharField(max_length=500,verbose_name="Fuel", null=True, blank=True)
          Seats = models.CharField(max_length=500,verbose_name="Seats", null=True, blank=True)
          Door = models.CharField(max_length=500,verbose_name="Door", null=True, blank=True)
          M3 = models.CharField(max_length=500,verbose_name="M3", null=True, blank=True)
          Dimensions = models.CharField(max_length=500,verbose_name="Dimensions", null=True, blank=True)
          Weight = models.CharField(max_length=500,verbose_name="Vehicle Weight", blank=True, null=True)
          MaxCap = models.CharField(max_length=500,verbose_name="Max Capicity", null=True, blank=True)
          country = models.ForeignKey(Country, verbose_name="CountryName", on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
          pricerange = models.ForeignKey(PriceRange, verbose_name="Price Range", on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
          discount = models.ForeignKey(Discount, verbose_name="By Discount", on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
          othercategorie = models.ForeignKey(OtherCategorie, verbose_name="Other Categories", on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
          Description = models.TextField(verbose_name="Description", null=True, blank=True)
          Price = models.CharField(max_length=500,verbose_name="Vehicla Price", null=True, blank=True)
          TotalPrice = models.CharField(max_length=500,verbose_name="Total Price", null=True, blank=True)

          @staticmethod
          def get_all_cars():
              return Car.objects.all()

          @staticmethod
          def get_all_cars_by_CompanyId(company_id):
              if company_id:
                  return Car.objects.filter(company=company_id)
              else:
                  return Car.get_all_cars()

          def __str__(self):
              return self.CarName
```

**searchdd.html**

```
  {% for cars in searchresult %}            
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 mt-3">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-horizontal row">
                            <div class="img-square-wrapper col-md-4">
                                <img class="img-fluid" height="400px" width="400px" src="{{cars.CarImage.url}}" alt="Card image cap">
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body col-md-8">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <!-- <div class="col">{{cars.CarName}}</div>
                                    <div class="col">{{cars.type}}</div>
                                    <div class="col">{{cars.RefNo}}</div>
                                    <div class="col">{{cars.ChassisNo}}</div> -->
                                    <table class="table-detailed-spec table-bordered col-md-10">
                                        <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="th th-1st">{{cars.CarName}}</td>
                                            <td class="td-1st">{{cars.type}}</td>
                                            <td class="th th-2nd">{{cars.RefNo}}</td>
                                            <td class="td-2nd">{{cars.ChassisNo}}</td>
                                            <td class="th th-3rd">{{cars.ModelCode}}</td>                                                                    
                                            <td class="td-3rd">{{cars.EngineSize}}</td>                    
                                            <td class="th th-4th">{{cars.Location}}</td>
                                            <td class="td-4th">{{cars.Version}}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="th th-1st">{{cars.Drive}}</td>
                                            <td class="td-1st">{{cars.Transmission}}</td>
                                            <td class="th th-2nd">{{cars.Registration}}</td>
                                            <td class="td-2nd">{{cars.Mileage}}</td>
                                            <td class="th th-3rd">{{cars.EngineCode}}</td>
                                            <td class="td-3rd">{{cars.Steering}}</td>
                                            <td class="th th-4th">{{cars.ExtColor}}</td>
                                            <td class="td-4th">{{cars.Fuel}}</td>
                                        </tr>                                                                                                                                                                                    </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                                
                                <!-- <h4 class="card-title">{{cars.CarName}}</h4>
                                <p class="card-text">{{cars.type}}</p> -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>        
    {% endfor %}
```

**views.py**

```
   def searchdd(request):

       companyname = request.GET.get('companyname')
       carname = request.GET.get('carname')
       fromdate = request.GET.get('fromdate')
       todate = request.GET.get('todate')
       typ = request.GET.get('typ')
       steering = request.GET.get('steering')

       searchresult = Car.objects.all()   
 
       if companyname !="" and companyname != "--Select Make--":
           searchresult = searchresult.filter(company__CompanyName=companyname)

       if carname !="" and carname !="--Select Model--":
           searchresult = searchresult.filter(CarName=carname)


       if fromdate !="" and fromdate !="--select Year--":
           searchresult = searchresult.filter(mdate__ManufacturingDate=fromdate)

       if todate !="" and todate !="--select Year--":
           searchresult = searchresult.filter(mdate__ManufacturingDate=todate)

       if typ !="" and typ !="--Select Type--":
           searchresult = searchresult.filter(type__TypeName=typ)

       if steering !="" and steering !="--Select Steering--":
           searchresult = searchresult.filter(steering__SteeringName=steering)
    
       context = {'searchresult':searchresult}
       return render(request, 'app/searchdd.html', context)
```

Comment: Are you sure that `mdate__ManufacturingDate=fromdate` is correct? Usually variables like `fromdate` and `todate` would indicate some usage of `__gte` and `__lte` when filtering.

Comment: Also, shouldn't `fromdate` be converted to a `datetime.date` instance before filtering? Right now, you are just using the string that came inside the GET request.

Comment: I have checked I have removed both dates (from date and to date) but still situation is same

Comment: can you please little guide me

Comment: If you do no filtering (leaving all GET parameters empty) does it return all the data then?

Comment: yes these all returning

Comment: Have you tried using one filter at the time to see if they individually work as expected? Only after establishing that, then you should try to combine them and see if the combination works as expected

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237646/discussion-between-daniyalakhtar-akhtar-and-ralf).